# cmd batch recall commands history

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have  a batch script that takes an url as argument and before doing the main operations of the script, It saves the url in a log file.
Is there a way to read the log file (when I execute it next time) and  add the entries to the history so it can be used (by UP KEY) like a recall history ?

Comment: There seems to be no easy and ideal way. See related posts: http://superuser.com/questions/257855/keep-cmd-exe-command-history-between-sessions  and http://serverfault.com/questions/95404/is-there-a-global-persistent-cmd-history

Comment: i know about [Clink](http://mridgers.github.io/clink/) , what i need is when i run the batch script, hit the **UP KEY** it prints the last  entered url to the batch script window , hit **enter** and the batch file will do the rest. the url can be read from the log file, is there some use of the **doskey** command to do this ?

Comment: You might want to delete your original question (as a duplicate) and launch a new one. State clearly what you have tried und were your stumbling blocks are.

Comment: As far as I know this can't be done. You could however, make it so that you could TAB through your URL history or TAB finish a half-typed URL. If this is good enough please comment and I will post how.

Comment: Please tell me, but I am not using the URL history of the system, its loged in a text file.

Comment: use powershell instead. Apart from being much more powerful than cmd, it's also easy to manually change the history in powershell

Answer (score 0):

it isn't that hard, you need to make a `log.txt` holding all the data.

Use this to add something in it:
`echo [action]>>log.txt`

And this to read it:
`for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%a in (a.txt) do echo %%a`

by the way, this is in @echo off

Comment: I just saw a comment where you explained what you want and this is not it, sorry for that.

Answer (score 0):

A very similar thing is possible using `For loops`, Line `counts`, an `Array` containing the stored Urls retrieved from the file, and the `Choice command` within a Loop to Page through the array.

[Here is an example](https://pastebin.com/5NgGCHXc)